# import/export in Typescript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have an existing Node.js (Node only, no Typescript) application with the following files (generated by Visual Studio Node template):

In file `app.js`:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
...
module.exports = app;
```

In file `socket.js`:

```
module.exports = function (server,app) {
   // ....
}
```

In file `www`:

```
var app = require("../app");
var server = app.listen(app.get(8081), function() {
});
var sockets = require("../routes/sockets")(server, app);
```

I am no migrating it to Typescript. How do I convert the above export/require to the equivalent in Typescript?

Where can I find the proper specifications of the `import` and `export` keywords? I am unable to find documentation of what they mean and do exactly. I do see many examples of *some* permutations of their usage.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your import statements will be transpiled into require(), you need to specify that you want to use commonjs modules during the TypeScript compilation. Here's an example of tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "build",
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Here's an example of the Node/Express server in TypeScript:

```
import * as express from "express";
const app = express();

app.get('/products', (req, res) => res.send('Got a request for products'));

const server = app.listen(8000, "localhost", () => {

    const {address, port} = server.address();

    console.log('Listening on %s %s', address, port);
});
```

Comment: What will it transpile to if `commonjs` is not specified? Where can I find more information on what export/import does?

Comment: By default, it compiles to ES6 modules if the compilation target is ES6, otherwise to CommonJS. you can read about ES6 modules here: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html